# Why is setting the text of a Spinner in onCreateView throwing a null pointer exception?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to set the superficial text on a Spinner without having that text appear as an item in the spinner drop-down.

I'm getting a reference to the Spinner's TextView like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) spinner.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setText("TEST");
```

The problem is that it throws a NPE when calling the above code from the main body of onCreateView().

But if I comment out these lines in the main body of onCreateView(), it works fine when I set the text using the above code inside the spinner's `OnItemSelectedListener`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, parent, false);

    spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.array.options, 
                    R.layout.spinner_item);     
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                                   int position, long id) 
        {
            switch (position)
            {
            case 0: 
                // This works fine:
                TextView tv = (TextView)
                    spinner.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setText("TEST");
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {

        }           
    });

    // tv is always null on the line below
    TextView tv = (TextView) spinner.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setText("TEST");

    return v;
}
```

The Spinner itself is not null.  It's tv that is null.

Does anyone know why I can't get a reference to the Spinner's TextView here, and how I could get such a reference?

EDIT:

I solved it by adding an OnGlobalLayoutListener to the spinner's ViewTreeObserver:

```
spinner.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() 
            {
                spinner.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                TextView tv = (TextView) spinner.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);  
                tv.setText("TEST");
            }
        });
```

Comment: try Use android:prompt="@string/select" in spinner....

Comment: I need to be able to dynamically change the text during runtime.

Comment: ur id is wrong android.R.id.text1 use urpackage name packagename.R.id.text1

Comment: Then why is it working in the OnItemSelectedListener?

Answer (score 1):

The views in Spinner get created as part of the layout pass which will happen on a future iteration of the main message queue. You are trying to access the View before it is created, findViewById is returning null.

This will put the update on the main queue, so it occurs after layout.

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView tv = (TextView) spinner.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setText("TEST");
        }
    });
```

A better approach might be to have a custom subclass of Spinner, that does what you need ( maybe in onLayout )

Comment: I just tried it and it still throws a NPE at `tv.setText("TEST")`

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a hint on how to solve it.  I edited my original post with the solution.

Comment: Cool, then you should post your answer and accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

put this in onWindowFocusChange()

```
TextView tv = (TextView) spinner.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setText("TEST");
```